# Bresenham Line rasterization not connecting pixels

Tags: matlab, graphics, bresenham

I am trying to draw a line using Bresenham line algorithm, given starting (x1,y1) and ending (x2,y2) points. Every time when I try to draw the line, pixels are getting disconnected. I followed the Matlab solutions [Matlab Bresenham 8-connected](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab), [Bresenham 4-connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186939/algorithm-for-drawing-a-4-connected-line), [Bresenham any gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381269/line-rasterisation-cover-all-pixels-regardless-of-line-gradient) and DDA too.

But every time I try to draw the steep lines, pixels getting disconnected. I am not sure whether it is an issue with Matlab imshow.

Image what I am getting (blue line).

[image: Bresenham Result]

What I want is something exact as:

[image: Matlab Structuring Element]

Please note that I used structuring element (strel function in Matlab to produce binary image).

Can someone please help me on this? I appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: Bresenham requires the slope to be less than 1. If you have greater slopes, you need to use a different coordinate system, in which you have an appropriate slope (e.g. swap x/y). Btw, I really doubt that the blue line is the result of a Bresenham implementation.

Comment: See [this blog post](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/400) for a trivial implementation and clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with the screen resolution. On 13" MacBook Pro the blue line with steep gradient was disconnected. On high-resolution monitor like 22" (1920x1080) the steep blue lines are connecting well.

[Connected Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SPjF.png)