# Bresenham algorithm

Tags: algorithm, line, pixel, bresenham

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I create a line of arbitrary thickness using Bresenham?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222713/how-do-i-create-a-line-of-arbitrary-thickness-using-bresenham)

How can I use Bresenham algorithm to draw lines of more than a pixel thick? 
Do i have to run the algorithm many times with an offset from x and y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to calculate using the slope of the line, a unit offset in both orthogonal directions. Multiply this by your thickness, and take the offsets at both endpoints. You now have effectively the bounds of a rotated rectangle. Then, rather than using Bresenham to draw the line, use a fast polygon fill.

Comment: Well, the polygon fill is likely using Bresenham as well ;)

Comment: Ah true, when it walks the edges :)

Answer (score 2):

No, the simple way is just plot a stencil at every (x, y) location produced by the algorithm that is larger than one pixel, e.g. a disc.

But that's of course inefficient in the sense that you plot the same pixel many times. It's however easy to implement and works robustly with even odd-shaped or multicolored stencils.

Comment: Yeah, but (a) the oddshaped stencils are not the question (b) transparency kind-a ruins things (unless you want to also introduce an intermediate layer)