# OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile glLineWidth

Tags: opengl, osx-lion

I'm setting up a OpenGL 3.2 Core context on Mac OS X. I want to be able to draw some thick black likes on the screen. In pervious version of OpenGL, I could just set

```
glLineWidth(10.0f);
```

and I will get a line 10 pixels wide. However when I check the line width ranges in 3.2 Core

```
GLint range[2];
glGetIntegerv(GL_ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, range);
glGetIntegerv(GL_SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE, range);
```

I get the values of 1 for Aliased Lines and 0-1 for Smooth lines. How can I make a line that is 10.0 pixels wide in screen space? Is there a simple way to draw this other than making each line segment a rectangle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using OpenGL 3.2 core profile, calling *glLineWidth* with a value greater than 1.0 give an INVALID_VALUE error (call *glGetError* to prove it).

Surely you can get the wanted result by determining the quad required for drawing the line.

I think you should be able to generate quads from from line points: hey, a larger line is a quad! Maybe you could use techinques like [this](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter22.html) to get your wanted result.

The key is: instead of rely on LineWidth, you give a unit quad as input (4 vertices using triangle strip), then transform incoming vertices inside a shader passing to it appropriate uniforms.

Maybe another approach would be rendering using a geometry shader: generate a quad from a point. However, I'm not sure about this point. I don't know if a geometry shader (only if it feasible, of course) would be the best approach: the cost of drawing a line strip using a single quad would be the shader uniform setup for each line composing the strip.

Comment: It looks like the best/only way to do this is two draw the full geometry ether through the initial geometry or a geometry shader.

Comment: For those wondering where this restriction is documented, in GL3.3 spec it's in chapter E.2.1, not in 3.5 where `LineWidth` is documented.

Answer (score 1):

This could be depending on the type of projection you set up. Are you using orthographic or perspective projection matrix?

I think that if you are not using the orthographic projection, the final rasterisation of the primitive will be subject to the distance of the object (model matrix) from the camera (view matrix).

Cheers

Comment: I'm using orthographic projection.

Answer (score 1):

Line width > 1.0 is deprecated and not further supported in a core profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context).
However, it is still maintained in a compatibility profile context.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specificatio - E.2.1 Deprecated But Still Supported Features](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=700&zoom=100,168,758):

> The following features are deprecated, but still present in the core profile. They
>   may be removed from a future version of OpenGL, and are removed in a forwardcompatible context implementing the core profile.
>
> - Wide lines - LineWidth values greater than 1.0 will generate an INVALID_VALUE error

---

<sub>For a core profile context possible solutions are presented in the answers to:

[OpenGL Line Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484260/opengl-line-width)

[GLSL Geometry shader to replace glLineWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686818/glsl-geometry-shader-to-replace-gllinewidth)

[Drawing a variable width line in openGL (No glLineWidth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101718/drawing-a-variable-width-line-in-opengl-no-gllinewidth)

[OpenGL : thick and smooth/non-broken lines *in 3D*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655888/opengl-thick-and-smooth-non-broken-lines-in-3d/36663605)</sub>