# Is there and alternatice for gllinewidth in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

glLineWidth is not supported by openGL ES 2.0. Is there any alternative to achieve the same in 2.0?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101718/drawing-a-variable-width-line-in-opengl-no-gllinewidth

Comment: `glLineWidth` *is* supported in ES 2.0. See section 3.4 of [the spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf).

Comment: @rickster I think that's for lines without multisampling only. If the lines are anti aliased they show up as width 1.

Answer (score 0):

Render triangle strip or triangles instead. This will consume 2x more vertex memory, but should faster than lines on modern hw.
If You can target ES3 You can consider using instanced vertex arrays to lower vertex mem usage.