# glLineWidth is different on the device Cocos2d

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

HEre is my draw method.. Everything seems fine on ios6/7 & iPhone3/4/5 simulators but the lines are thinner on my iphone 5s.. I increase the line width to 100 but didnt work but if I decrease it, it works! And this is a cocos2d v2.1 project.

```
-(void) draw
{
    glEnable(0x0B20);

    ccDrawColor4F(0.22f, 0.82f, 0.00f, 1.00f);
    glLineWidth([[UIScreen main] scale] == 2 ? 32 : 16);

        ccDrawLine(ccp(0, 0), ccp(0, [[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue]));
        ccDrawLine(ccp(0, size.height), ccp(0, size.height - [[arr objectAtIndex:0] intValue]));

        for(int x = 0; x <= (size.width / 16); x++)
        {
            ccDrawLine(ccp(x*16 - offset, 0), ccp(x*16 - offset, [[arr objectAtIndex:x] intValue]));
            ccDrawLine(ccp(x*16 - offset, size.height), ccp(x*16 - offset, size.height - [[arr objectAtIndex:x] intValue]));
        }
}
```

Comment: draw filled polygons instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101718/drawing-a-variable-width-line-in-opengl-no-gllinewidth

Comment: Thanks.. I have ended up using `ccDrawSolidRect` :)